# Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-rds

Running:

```
Timeout.timeout(1) { User.find_by_sql('SELECT sleep(2) FROM users;') }
```

Returns the following:

```
  User Load (1004.2ms)  SELECT sleep(2) FROM users;
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: : execution expired: SELECT sleep(2) FROM users;
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:687:in `query'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:687:in `block in exec_query'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:244:in `block in log'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:239:in `log'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:685:in `exec_query'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:679:in `select'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:470:in `find_by_sql'
    from (irb):1:in `block in irb_binding'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `
```

The following does not appear to happen with PgSql. Is there a bug in Mysql2 or ActiveRecord?

I have read that this happens when there are too many connections, which mysql fails to handle. But why does this not happen with PgSql then?

PS. I am using Amazon RDS, if that makes a difference.

Comment: This worked for me: In config/database.yml, change `:reconnect` to `true`, and `:pool` to `20`. see similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773930/ruby-exception-occured-mysql2error-closed-mysql-connection/13714846#13714846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you doing this in `Timeout.timeout(1)` block, I think you should make timeout longer.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. As in most cases a web app will hit the db with many connections. The same command does not cause an error with PgSql

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it gives an error in MySql but not PgSql is that sleep is a valid Mysql function but not a valid Pgsql function. The correct function in the latter is pg_sleep.
That said, the query sleeps for 2 seconds while in the Ruby code you limit the execution by 1 second, so a timeout exception is raised. For the Pg case, it should give an exception of another kind, something like "sleep is not a valid pgsql function"