# Ruby - Exception occured: [Mysql2::Error] closed MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have a Rails application now only runs internally, so there's not so much visits right now. And there're two resque worker running hardly to fetch data from the web and inserts into a mysql database, every insert will followed by sleep 10 second.

We run it on a VPS. After like every 5 hours, I will encounter an Exception `Exception occured: [Mysql2::Error] closed MySQL connection"`.

What could be the reason causing the exception? Now the pool size is 5.

Will it help if I raise the pool size and specify `reconnect: true` in my `database.yml`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a common issue when using the mysql2 gem version 0.2.11 or below in combination with multithreading. There is [a bug on the issue tracker](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/209) with a details on the problem but in conclusion the advice is to:

1. Update the gem version you are using to `>= 0.2.12`
2. Add the `reconnect: true` option your db connection config in the `database.yml` file

You probably already solved your problem but this might help others who come across this question.

Comment: The `reconnect: true` thing fixed it for me. (I'm already using a version well above 0.2.12.)

Answer (score 1):

If your workers are inactive for a long period of time, they'll lose their MySQL connection.

see [here](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/activerecord-threading-issues-and-resolutions/) for the solution

or just stick this in an initializer

```
unless Rails.env.to_s == 'test'
  module ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters
    class Mysql2Adapter
      alias_method :execute_without_retry, :execute

    def execute(*args)
      execute_without_retry(*args)
      rescue Exception => e
        if e.message =~ /server has gone away/i
          warn "Server timed out, retrying"
          reconnect!
          retry
        else
          raise e
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, john. After posted this message, I raised pool to 20 and added `reconnect: true` to my database.yml and it looks fixed. I think it does the same thing as you suggested, is it?

Answer (score 0):

More insight on how to debug this for **delayed_job**. I did the following after setting `reconnect: true` on `database.yml`, and this solution not working.

```
cd /your_rails_deploy_code/log
cat production.log

# check the pids from delayed job:
E, [2017-02-01T19:45:21.614579 #2592] ERROR -- : 2017-02-01T19:45:21+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.3 host:demeter pid:2592)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=193675) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection
```

On my specific case, `pid:2592` is the only one constantly failing. Why? Let's find out:

```
[deploy@demeter] ps -ef | grep 2592
deploy   2592     1  0 Jan31 ?        00:00:40 production/delayed_job.3
deploy   23312     1  0 Feb01 ?        00:00:40 production/delayed_job.1
deploy   23318     1  0 Feb01 ?        00:00:40 production/delayed_job.0
```

I noticed that specific process started days before my latest deploy. As soon as I killed it, the errors were gone. What I assume happened on my specific case was that my latest deploy did not delete all delayed_job instances correctly.